# Adding View to RegionManager in C# Module Does Not Work

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am in the process of converting a VB.NET PRISM Module to C#.  It is a very simple affair that currently works in VB.NET.  It displays a string value that is bound to a ViewModel.

The XAML for the View (I switched it to hard-coded text in an effort to force its display, normally it is a databound control):

```
<UserControl x:Class="StatusBarAlarmsView"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                     mc:Ignorable="d" 
                     MinWidth="150">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Garrison" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The following code works in VB to display the View:

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion, 
    Function() container.Resolve(Of iSBAlarmsPresenter).view)
```

I attempted the same thing with converted C# code, and it looks like this:

```
this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion,
    () => new StatusBarAlarmsView());
```

I have tried multiple permutations of the above C#, all without success:

```
// One
var statusbarRegion = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.statusBarRegion];
var test = new StatusBarAlarmsView();
test.ViewModel = new AlarmViewModel(this.logger, this.eventAggregator, null, 
    this.container);
statusbarRegion.Add(test);

// Two
this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion,
    () => container.Resolve<iSBAlarmsPresenter>().View);
```

I won't go into the detail of how the View and ViewModel hook up, because currently I'm not concerned about that--I just want it to display "Garrison".

**Additional Info**
Using Snoop, I can drill down into the StatusBar Region.  I can see the other items displayed in that region, and they all have their DataContexts set as expected.

With my Alarm Module, however, the ContentPresenter does not have an inherited DataContext, it is marked as Local, which is different from all of the other items in the region.  When I attempt to view the DataContext of the bottommost ContentPresenter, I am told the "object is NULL".

All of this is beside the point, though, because my View is being loaded into the tree, and yet my TextBlock is not displaying.

**Updates**
As requested, XAML markup for the StatusBar Region:

```
<Grid Name="StatusBarGrid" Grid.Row="3" Height="30">
    <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:GridHeightModifyOnFontChangeBehavior FontSize="{DynamicResource AppFontSize}"/>
    </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <DockPanel >
        <WrapPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Right"  cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.statusBarRightRegion}" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"   />
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Left"  cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.statusBarRegion}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: "Additional Info Using Snoop, I can drill down into the StatusBar Region. I can see the other items displayed in that region, and they all have their DataContexts set as expected."

Are you registering more than 1 view into that region?  If so, only the first View that's registered will be visible until you do a navigation.  If not, posting the XAML for where you created the regions would help.

Comment: @TTat I've updated the bottom of the post with the Region markup.  This StatusBar region displays 5 different Views, all side by side at the bottom of the application window.

Comment: Just clarifying.  You're doing something like this?
this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion,
    () => new StatusView1());
this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion,
    () => new StatusView2()); ... this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion,
    () => new StatusBarAlarmsView());

Comment: Each of the modules that display in the StatusBarRegion register their Views with the RegionManager during their initialization, so the code isn't all run at the same time, but yes, it's effectively similar to this.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I need to ask: Are you invoking the InitializeComponent method in the constructor of the StatusBarAlarmsView?

Comment: It's not a dumb question--I'm new to WPF and MVVM (all past jobs have been Web programming).  I will check and try if that's not the case.

Comment: @DamianCherubini That was it!  Add your suggestion as an answer and the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you invoking the InitializeComponent method in the constructor of the StatusBarAlarmsView?

A common mistake when addapting views (specially if you need to modify the constructors of those views) is to forget about calling the InitializeComponent method. This method "tells" the view to create and render its inner components. If it's not invoked you will usually find your view looking empty because its components were never created.

Comment: Have to wait an hour to award bounty--will do so soon.  Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. I remember having this same issue myself a couple of times before and it was pretty frustrating. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I THINK you're trying to show all 5 status views at the same time in your Status Region?  That isn't possible.  The first View that's registered in the Region will be visible and active.  The others you registered won't show up until you navigate to it.

Try doing this somewhere after everything is loaded to see if your StatusBarAlarmsView shows up.

```
this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.statusBarRegion, new Uri("StatusBarAlarmsView", UriKind.Relative));
```

Also let the container create your views for you so it can handle the view models and all the dependencies:

```
this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion, typeof(StatusBarAlarmsView));
```

Comment: Each of the Views shows something different, and is its own View/VM and Module.  They currently all work and display together in the StatusBar control.  This module/code works in VB, and displays as expected.  It doesn't work when using the same code in C#.

Comment: Yes, but each region can only show 1 View at a time.  You're trying to register 5 different Views into your RegionNames.statusBarRegion right?  Only the first one that was registered will be visible.  Anything after that is registered but will not be active until you "Navigate" to that view.

Comment: I checked and all of the modules call the same code: `regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.statusBarRegion, 
    Function() container.Resolve(Of IxxxPresenter).view)`.  Each of the modules have their own Presenter interface and implementation that all have disparate View/VM implementations.  There isn't anything shared between them.  And they all display at the same time.  The code also doesn't have a single RequestNavigate() call.

Comment: If you're loading more than one module in your application and they are ALL trying to register a view into the "StatusBarRegion" only the FIRST view that registers will be displayed until you navigate to one of the other Views.  Think of registering the Views into the region as placing a card in that area.  Every time you register another view it places it at the bottom of the stack.  When you "Navigate" you're selecting the "card" you want to see and placing it on top.

Comment: I don't want to be contradictory, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Imagine 5 bricks laid on a foundation, and that's exactly how these Views are displayed in the one region.  This is working code, working modules, that I'm trying to convert to C#.  This is not code that I'm trying to get to work.  And I appreciate your help!

Comment: So I looked into it a little bit, and it looks like you can have multiple Views in a region if it inherits from ItemsControl (which StatusBar does).  ContentControl (the one I typically use) only allows 1 active view.  Sorry about that.  Have you tried not loading anything except the Alarm module?  Have you tried registering it the way posted?

Comment: Yes, I've also attempted to register it with the `typeof()`.  Forgot to mention it in my post.  I have not tried just loading the Alarm module, will see what happens with that.